# How can I pre-populate my input with data from API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have an edit form, and I'm trying to populate my input base on the response from API. My **campaign** data look like this.

```
{
    "id": 219,
    "name": "finishedddd-1642606412049"
}
```

[image]

**Testing**

You see that I can access `campaign.name` like this

```
<p>Campaign Name : {{ campaign.name }}</p>
```

**Trying**

I want to pre-populated my name input, so I did this

```
data() {
    return {
        campaign: {},
        form: {
            errors: {},
            values: {
                name: this.campaign.name,
                ...
```

**Result**

Somehow that kept getting me :

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

[image]

**Code**

```
<template>
    <v-container fluid class="my-1">
        <Navbar />
        <Breadcrumbs />
        <v-row>
            <v-col cols="12">
                <v-card elevation="2">
                    <PanelHeader type="create" icon="campaign" title="Campaigns" />

                    <v-stepper v-model="e1" justify="center" elevation="0">
                        <v-stepper-header>
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 1" step="1"> Campaign </v-stepper-step>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-stepper-step :complete="e1 > 2" step="2"> Setup </v-stepper-step>
                            <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <v-stepper-step step="3"> Finish </v-stepper-step>
                        </v-stepper-header>

                        <v-stepper-items>
                            <v-stepper-content step="1">
                                <v-card class="mb-12" elevation="0">
                                    <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation v-model="valid" id="form">
                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold">
                                                Campaigns

                                                <p>Campaign Name : {{ campaign.name }}</p>

                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>Select marketing campaign type for Print Materials or Product Tags. Provide a name to identify the marketing campaign.</span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                <v-select disabled dense outlined :items="types" label="Type" v-model="form.values.type" :rules="form.rules.type"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.name" :rules="form.rules.name" label="Name" required></v-text-field>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>
                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <v-textarea dense rows="1" outlined v-model="form.values.description" label="Description" required></v-textarea>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold"
                                                >Schedule :

                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>Set the time zone, start and end date for this campaign to be active.</span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <v-select dense outlined :items="timezones" v-model="form.values.timezone" :rules="form.rules.timezone" label="Timezone" append-icon="lock_clock"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu v-model="form.values.startDateMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.startDate" :rules="form.rules.startDate" label="Start Date" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-date-picker v-model="form.values.startDate"></v-date-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="startTimeMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" :return-value.sync="form.values.startTime" transition="scale-transition" offset-y max-width="290px" min-width="290px">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense v-model="form.values.startTime" label="Start Time" append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" outlined></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-time-picker v-if="startTimeMenu" v-model="form.values.startTime" full-width @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.startTime)"></v-time-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu v-model="endDateMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" transition="scale-transition" offset-y min-width="auto">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.endDate" :rules="form.rules.endDate" :min="form.values.startDate" label="End Date" append-icon="mdi-calendar" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-date-picker v-model="form.values.endDate"></v-date-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-menu ref="menu" v-model="endTimeMenu" :close-on-content-click="false" :nudge-right="40" :return-value.sync="form.values.endTime" transition="scale-transition" offset-y max-width="290px" min-width="290px">
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-text-field dense v-model="form.values.endTime" label="End Time" append-icon="mdi-clock-time-four-outline" readonly v-bind="attrs" v-on="on" outlined></v-text-field>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <v-time-picker v-if="endTimeMenu" v-model="form.values.endTime" :min="form.values.startTime" full-width @click:minute="$refs.menu.save(form.values.endTime)"></v-time-picker>
                                                </v-menu>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>
                                    </v-form>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn color="primary" @click="validate()" :disabled="!valid"> Continue </v-btn>
                                <router-link :to="`/${segment1}`">
                                    <v-btn text> Cancel </v-btn>
                                </router-link>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="2">
                                <v-card class="mb-12" elevation="0">
                                    <v-form ref="form2" lazy-validation v-model="valid2" id="form2">
                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold">
                                                Destination

                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>The scan destination is the end point for a consumer experience. Can be single URL or use URL Groups. </span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-col class="col-sm-2 col-lg-2 col-12">
                                                <v-select dense outlined :items="urlTypes" label="Single or Multi URL" v-model="form.values.urlType" :rules="form.rules.urlType"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>
                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="2">
                                                <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.url" :rules="form.rules.url" label="URL" required></v-text-field>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>

                                        <v-row>
                                            <v-card-text class="font-weight-bold"
                                                >Conditions :

                                                <v-tooltip right>
                                                    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                                        <v-btn icon v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">
                                                            <v-icon color="grey lighten-1">info</v-icon>
                                                        </v-btn>
                                                    </template>
                                                    <span>Set the conditions for a campaign. If all conditions are true, this campaign will trigger for consumer experience.</span>
                                                </v-tooltip>
                                            </v-card-text>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <v-select dense outlined :items="attributes" item-text="name" item-value="id" v-model="form.values.attribute" :rules="form.rules.attribute" label="Attribute"></v-select>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="1">
                                                <v-combobox v-model="operator" :items="operators" item-text="operator" item-value="id" label="Operator" outlined dense></v-combobox>
                                            </v-col>

                                            <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="4">
                                                <!-- <v-text-field dense outlined v-model="form.values.value" :rules="form.rules.value" label="Values" required></v-text-field> -->

                                                <v-text-field v-model="value" :items="values" label="Value" multiple outlined dense></v-text-field>
                                            </v-col>
                                        </v-row>
                                    </v-form>
                                </v-card>

                                <v-btn color="primary" @click="validate2()" :disabled="!valid2"> Update </v-btn>

                                <v-btn text @click="e1 = 1"> Back </v-btn>
                            </v-stepper-content>

                            <v-stepper-content step="3"> </v-stepper-content>
                        </v-stepper-items>
                    </v-stepper>
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from '../../../components/Navbar'
import Breadcrumbs from '../../../components/Breadcrumbs'
import PanelHeader from '../../../components/PanelHeader'
import axios from 'axios'
import moment from 'moment-timezone'

export default {
    components: {
        Navbar,
        Breadcrumbs,
        PanelHeader
    },
    beforeMount() {},
    computed: {
        segment1: function () {
            const firstSegment = new URL(window.location.href).pathname.split('/')[1]
            return `${firstSegment}`
        },
        timeZone: function () {
            console.log('timeZone')
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {},

    mounted() {
        this.getCampaign()
    },

    data() {
        return {
            campaign: {},
            form: {
                errors: {},
                values: {
                    name: this.campaign.name,
                    type: 'Marketing',
                    description: null,
                    timezone: 'America/New_York',
                    startDate: new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                    endDate: new Date(Date.now() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000).toISOString().substr(0, 10),
                    startTime: moment().format('HH:mm'),
                    endTime: '24:00',
                    urlType: 'Single',
                    url: 'https://',
                    attribute: '',
                    operator: '',
                    value: ''
                },
                rules: {
                    type: [(v) => !!v || 'Type is required'],
                    name: [(v) => !!v || 'Name is required'],
                    startDate: [(v) => !!v || 'Start Date is required'],
                    endDate: [(v) => !!v || 'End Date is required'],
                    timezone: [(v) => !!v || 'Timezone is required'],
                    startTime: [(v) => !!v || 'Start Time is required'],
                    endTime: [(v) => !!v || 'End Time is required'],
                    urlType: [(v) => !!v || 'URL Type is required'],
                    url: [(v) => !!v || 'URL is required'],
                    attribute: [(v) => !!v || 'Attribute is required'],
                    operator: [(v) => !!v || 'Operator is required'],
                    value: [(v) => !!v || 'Value is required']
                }
            },
            e1: 1,
            valid: false,
            valid2: false,
            types: ['Product', 'Marketing'],
            operator: [],
            operators: ['=', '!=', 'in', 'not in'],
            value: [],
            values: ['Italy', 'Finland', 'Norway'],
            timezones: moment.tz.names(),
            startDateMenu: false,
            endDateMenu: false,
            startTimeMenu: false,
            endTimeMenu: false,
            urlTypes: ['Single', 'Multiple'],
            attributes: []
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'form.values.attribute'() {
            this.operator = null
            axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
            let data = {
                $root: 'vc_operator',
                op: 'read',
                brand: 'COLM',
                selection: {
                    filters: [`id:${this.form.values.attribute}`]
                },
                _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
            }
            axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, data).then((response) => {
                this.operators = response.data.operators
            })
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getAllData(id) {
            let myForm = document.getElementById(id)
            console.log(
                Array.from(myForm.elements).map((e) => {
                    return e.value
                })
            )
        },
        validate() {
            this.$refs.form.validate()

            if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
                let data = {
                    $root: 'vc_rule_attribute',
                    op: 'read',
                    brand: 'COLM',
                    _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
                }

                axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'applcation/json'
                axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, data).then((response) => {
                    this.attributes = response.data.rule_attributes
                })
                this.e1 = 2
                console.info(this.form.values)
            } else {
                console.info(this.form.values)
            }
        },
        validate2() {
            this.$refs.form2.validate()
            if (this.$refs.form2.validate()) {
                let data = {
                    id: this.form.values.id,
                    name: this.form.values.name,
                    description: this.form.values.description,
                    start_date: this.form.values.startDate,
                    end_date: this.form.values.endDate,
                    priority: '100',
                    status_id: 1,
                    type_id: 1
                }

                let body = {
                    $root: 'vc_campaign',
                    op: 'update',
                    brand: 'COLM',
                    campaigns: [data],
                    _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
                }

                // this.$store
                //  .dispatch('editCampaign', body)
                //  .then(() => {
                //      this.$router.push({
                //          path: `/campaigns`
                //      })
                //  })
                //  .catch((err) => {
                //      console.log('Something went wrong: ', err)
                //  })
            } else {
                console.info(this.form.values)
            }
        },
        displayTime(time) {
            time = time.split(':')[0]
            if (time > 12) {
                return 'PM'
            } else {
                return 'AM'
            }
        },
        getCampaign() {
            let filters = 'id:' + this.$route.params.id
            let body = {
                $root: 'vc_campaign',
                op: 'read',
                brand: 'COLM',
                selection: {
                    filters: [filters]
                },
                _SESSION: localStorage.getItem('session')
            }

            axios.defaults.headers['Content-Type'] = 'applcation/json'
            axios
                .post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body)
                .then((response) => {
                    if (response.data.status == 0) {
                        this.campaign = response.data.campaigns[0]
                    } else {
                        alert(response.data.statustext)
                        reject(response.data.statustext)
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('Something went wrong: ', err)
                })
        }
    }
}
</script>

<style></style>
```

Comment: Do you intend to updated the values object? Or is to going be read-only?

Comment: Since this the edit view. yes users should be able to modify it & save.

Comment: Okay & do you want `this.form.data.values.name` always point to the `this.campaign.name`?

Comment: Yes, I just want to load the values from API and in filled into the appropriate inputs. Why is this so hard in Vue.js ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are basically trying to access a variable which is not defined yet. data() is called only once when you initialize the component. This happens way before you get the response from api and assign a value to this.campaign.

That's why this line doesn't work:

```
name: this.campaign.name
```

What you can do instead is something like this:

```
data() {
    return {
        campaign: {},
        form: {
            errors: {},
            values: {
                name: "",
                ...
getCampaign() {
    ...
    axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT_URL}`, body)
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.data.status == 0) {
                this.campaign = response.data.campaigns[0]
                this.form.values.name = this.campaign.name
                ...
```

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping your requirements in mind, you can use `watch` property to keep both the values in sync

Set the initial `form.values.name` to `''`

```
data() {
    return {
        campaign: {},
        form: {
            errors: {},
            values: {
                name: '',
                ...
```

and to keep the values in sync, you can do something like this:

```
watch: {
  campaign: {
      handler(newVal) {
          this.form.values.name = newVal.name
      },
      immediate: true
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the idea, but I still have so many questions. Do I move my getCampaign() into the watch property ? Please kindly update your answer with my respective codes (if possible).

Comment: You don't need to move your `getCampaign()` inside the watch. What the code above does is, whenever `this.campaign` gets updated (which happens when you get a response from the api call), the handler function gets called along with the new value of `this.campaign`. Then we are assigning new campaign's name to `form.values.name`. The benefit of using this approach is, if you change the value of `this.campaign` from any where in your component (not just in `getCampaign()`), `this.form.values.name` will automatically be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<p>Campaign Name : {{ campaign?.name }}</p>`

Comment: You mean in the form ? I tried that ... no error, but also not working. Please explain your suggestions.

Comment: Please kindly update your answer.